# Thermal conductivity in GROMACS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs, thermal

Is there any way we can calculate thermal conductivity in GROMACS? I can see the equilibrium Green-Kubo method algorithm, or non-equilibrium Muller-Plathe algorithm implemented in LAMMPS, but don't think either of these algorithms is implemented in GROMACS. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but did you figure out an answer yet? Are you still actively needing the answer? Please update us!